# How to set custom date and manipulate data in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my project which returns a sum of amount from today's date to coming 49 days. I want to modify this stored procedure in a way that it would take 2014-01-01 as the start date and return the data from that date. For an example,

```
Total_amount     StartDate    EndDate
50000           2014-01-01    2014-02-18
40000           2014-02-19    2014-04-08
```

This is my stored procedure,

```
USE [myDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_sp] 

AS
BEGIN
    select sum(amount) as Total_amount,
           getdate() as StartDate,
           dateadd(dd, 48, dateadd(dd, -(datepart(dw, getdate())-2), getdate())) as EndDate
    from   my_table
    where  Col_Date > dateadd(dd, -1, getdate())
           and Col_Date < dateadd(dd, 49, dateadd(dd, -(datepart(dw, getdate())-2), getdate()))
END
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the start date to be a parameter of always 1/1/2014?

Comment: Yes, I want the start date to be always 1/1/2014.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach based on my better understanding of your goal.  I use a Common Table Expression to set up a table that provides the 49 day 'buckets' and then joins against that list to sum up the appropriate totals.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_sp] (@startdate datetime)

AS

BEGIN
-------------------------
-- Set up a table that lists off 49 day periods starting from @startDate
-------------------------

DECLARE @endDate DATETIME  = getdate(); 

WITH [dates] ([startDate], [maxDate_Excluded]) AS 
   (SELECT 
          @startDate AS [startDate] 
          ,DATEADD(d, 49, @startDate) AS [maxDate_Excluded] 

    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
          DATEADD(d, 49, [startDate]) AS [startDate] 
          ,DATEADD(d, 98, [startDate]) AS [maxDate_Excluded]
    FROM [dates] 
    WHERE [startDate] < @endDate
) 
, dateFrame AS
( 
    SELECT 
          [startDate] 
          ,[maxDate_Excluded]

    FROM [dates] 
)


-------------------------
-- JOIN and sum.
-------------------------
SELECT
    [startDate]
    , dateadd(d, -1, [maxDate_Exclued]) as endingDate
    , Sum(amount) as total_amount
FROM
    dateFrame df

    left join my_table mt
        on mt.col_date >= df.startDate
        and mt.col_date < df.maxDate_Excluded
GROUP BY
    [startDate]
    ,[maxDate_Excluded]
ORDER by
    [startDate]

END
```

Answer (score 0):

The getdate() function returns todays date. Hence you can change this to eg '2014-01-01'.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, you want to know how to add a date parameter to your stored procedure.  Then you want to use that supplied date instead of today's date in the procedure.

This is not too hard to do:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_sp] (@startdate datetime)

AS
BEGIN
    select sum(amount) as Total_amount,@startdate as StartDate,dateadd(dd,48,dateadd(dd,-(datepart(dw,@startdate)-2),@startdate)) as EndDate
    from my_table
    where Col_Date > dateadd(dd,-1,@startdate)
      and Col_Date < dateadd(dd,49,dateadd(dd,-(datepart(dw,@startdate)-2),@startdate))
END
```

Comment: Yes. But I want a loop there to start from the @startdate and keep adding 49 days to it until today.

Comment: What? Why do you need a loop? And why both with a loop if you just want all days through today?

Comment: I have a requirement to fetch the total_amount for all the 49 days period starting from this year.

Comment: So... you need to make sequential 'buckets' of 49 days and sum all the total_amounts in those buckets.  You want the buckets to begin on '1/1/2014' and end on the current date.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like LAG (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand must be like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[my_sp] 

AS
BEGIN
    select sum(amount) as Total_amount,
           getdate() as StartDate,
           dateadd(dd, 48, dateadd(dd, -(datepart(dw, getdate())-2), getdate())) as EndDate
    from   my_table
    where  Col_Date > '2014-01-01'
END
```